# Rails Routing Error only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, production-environment

Hello i have this in routes.rb

```
  namespace :admin do
    root :to => "admin#index"
    resources :employees
    resources :customers
    resources :users
  end
```

frontend normally works, i can login to administration but there i have link like

`<li><%= link_to "users", admin_users_path %></li>`

etc..

if i click on that link i get this error

```
uninitialized constant Admin::UsersController
```

or if i click on admin_employees_path i get

```
uninitialized constant Admin::EmployeesController
```

and that behavior is at every link in administration

at server with `rails s` everything is fine :p

user controller is defined like that

```
class UsersController < Admin::AdminController
```

files location
controllers/admin/admin_controller.rb
controllers/users_controller.rb

My environments files

**development.rb**

```
Web::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

**production.rb**

```
Web::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true # different
  config.assets.compress = true # different

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true # temporary true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # not in development
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

Comment: Try to check what's special in production.rb than development.rb?

Comment: hello i edited question and posted my environment files, its almost default only compile and request_local i change what i remember but thats should be okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining your users resource under the admin namespace but not defining it in the controller.

Move your users_controller to /controllers/admin/users_controller and append the namespace to that class declaration

`class Admin::UsersController < Admin::AdminController`

Or move your 
resources :user outside the admin namespace.

Comment: Your problem could be the config.cache_classes = false, since it's trying to cache the classes in production mode, it can't find them by convention. It's not trying to cache them in development mode, just a guess, try to play with those settings and let me know.

Comment: i have one more question on you.. how can i fix that path ? if i move controllers to admin folder im getting `raise LoadError, "Expected #{file_path} to define #{qualified_name}"` ? :-)

Comment: have models to copy folder struction from controllers ? if i copy models to models/admin folder im again getting uninitialized constant :P